# Why does this converge or diverge? (Improper Integral)

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I am trying to find the interval of convergence for this integral.
I am falling flat on the last step, and do not understand why the value of p matters (Except that p=1 causes a div by zero)

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's written in handwriting that's hard to read, when the OP knows how to typeset math, or should, with a rep of 2000

Comment: Hard to read?  You need glasses?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\lim_{b\to 0^+} b^e=\infty$$

For $e<0$ and

$$\lim_{b\to 0^+} b^e=0$$

For $e>0$

Also for $p=1$, you have to recall the antiderivative of $\int \frac{1}{x} \ dx$

Comment: So, you're saying [A....] Small number (<1) raised to a small number (<1) goes to INF.   [B....]  Small number raised to (>1) goes to 0.   So, in my example,  ln(2) < 1, so when p>1, it is neither case.  It is [C...] small number (<1) raised to a negative.